# response.sendRedirect() does not redirect to callback after Twitter login

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, twitter4j

I create web application where I have frontend in React JS and backend in Java Spring Boot. In frontend I have button with event onClick which have fetch to /signin in the backend. There (in the backend) I have two @GetMapping methods. First is http://localhost:8080/signin and second http://localhost:8080/callback. When I debug in /signin method response.sendRedirect(url) does not redirect me to callback function - /callback. In the twitter developer account I have good set callback url which is http://localhost:8080/callback . In addition, when I debug 
method with mapping /signin I don't get twitter form login. I don't know why. Anyone can help me ?

Here is my code

Backend

TwitterController

```
@RestController
public class TwitterController {

@GetMapping("/signin")
public void loginWithTwitter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxx")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxx");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("twitter", twitter);
    try {
        StringBuffer callbackURL = request.getRequestURL();
        int index = callbackURL.lastIndexOf("/");
        callbackURL.replace(index, callbackURL.length(), "").append("/callback");

        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackURL.toString());
        request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);

        response.sendRedirect(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}

@GetMapping("/callback")
public void loginWithTwitterCallback(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws TwitterException, ServletException, IOException {
    Twitter twitter = (Twitter) request.getSession().getAttribute("twitter");

    RequestToken requestToken = (RequestToken) request.getSession().getAttribute("requestToken");
    String verifier = request.getParameter("oauth_verifier");

    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("requestToken");

}
}
```

Frontend

LogIn.js

```
class LogIn extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onTwitterClick = this.onTwitterClick.bind(this);
}

onTwitterClick() {
    fetch("/signin", {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonData => {
        console.log(jsonData);
    });
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="login-container">
            <div className="login-form-container form-container-shadow form-size">
                <div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.onTwitterClick}>
                        LOGIN WITH TWITTER
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default withTranslation('common')(LogIn);
```

Comment: Try this without the React front end first. Just hit http://localhost:8080/signin with your browser and see if the callback method will be called. It might help to put logging.level.org.springframework=debug in application.properties so that you can see exactly what's happening in the back end.

Comment: If the problem is the React application, you might be getting blocked by CORS policy. Are you serving the React app from the Spring Boot application or a separate server?

Comment: @NazaretK. I put localhost:8080/signin in my browser and my callback method has been called. Firstly debugger went in to /signin method, redirect me to tweeter form login, I logged in and was redirected to callback function where I got access token. I think that my React JS application has problem.. I serve backend and frontend on separate localhosts. For spring 8080 and for react 3000. So everything works, but why I can not do this from my frontend? Why this does not work ?

Comment: Then it's a definitely a problem with CORS. Can't give more details right now, but will get back to you.

Comment: If I will make window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/signin' instead of fetch in event click everything work fine, but after callback and receive access token I don't know how redirect user again back to react application on localhost:3000/dashboard

Comment: Well, in your /callback controller, right in the end, you can just put a response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:3000"); That should work I think. Basically, its surprising but I think Twitter doesn't allow you to use the javascript way of calling the oauth api.

Comment: That is it. Login with twitter works, but when I did response.sendRedirect("localhost:3000/dashboard") I was redirected to localhost:3000/login because /dashboard have wrapper HOC's withAuth() where I check that jwtToken expired or not exsist. How redirect me to some method in LogIn component? After this authorization I would like to set localStorage for jwtToken, but I don't know how invoke method from frontend after redirect from backend. Can you help me ?

Comment: I guess your dashboard Component could do an http call to the back-end to check if the user is authenticated and get back the jwtToken as a response, which can then store. This assumes an http session is established between the browser and the back-end, which I think it is, since the same JSESSIONID is transmitted in requests/responses regardless of the port (3000 or 8080).

Comment: I don't know how indetify to this is that user. How indetify that this is specified user. Any idea ?

Comment: The java session does that automatically. As soon as the browser hits the signin method, you are creating an http session, so the server responds with the JSESSIONID cookie. This is sent by the browser on every call so that's how the server can identify which user the request is coming from. You just need to do request.getSession( ) in the server and the user specific data will be available automatically.